# Prove whether $f(n)$ is $O$, $o$, $\Omega$, $\omega$ or $\Theta$ of $g(n)$. $f(n) = n$, $g(n) = (\log n)^c$ for positive integer $c$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

So I'm completely new to Big O notation and time complexity and here is my attempt so far.
$$
\frac{f(n)}{ g(n)} =  \frac{n}{ (\log n)^c}
$$
and since $\log n$ grows slower than $n$, as $n$ approaches infinity the limit is also infinity.

I think this is correct, but I'm not sure how the notation works.

If you could explain how to apply big O notation to this it would be very helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You showed that $\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}\rightarrow +\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$.
Therefore :
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} \dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)} = 0$$
So that $g(n) = o(f(n))$ by definition of the o notation.

Comment: But the question asks for what f(n) is of g(n) not the other way around, do you mind explaining how the notation works? Thank you!

Comment: You can also write $f(n) = \omega(g(n))$. It is just a matter of definition. The result you showed lets you write that $f(n) = \omega(g(n))$. I suggest that you go read the definitions of asymptotic notations on wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Comment: Alright so that makes a bit more sense, I have one last question! I hope you don't mind! How can I check if f(n) is any of the other notations ? (like Omega or something)